# Get all image/attachment IDs in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to dislay wordpress gallery in single.php. I put this code into single.php

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="4" ids="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"]');?>
```

The problem is that image ids are changing based on post ID.

I wonder what code should I put? I did:

```
    <?php 
        $id_image = what_code_should_i_put_here;
        echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="4" ids="'.$id_image.'"]');
    ?>
```

But I have no idea the code part.

`what_code_should_i_put_here` must result `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'`

Comment: Did you check this one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149268/get-all-image-ids-from-the-media-library ?

After you get IDs array, you would simply need to convert it to delimited string. Let me know if you need help on that.

Comment: @NerijusMasikons That's what I am looking for. Thank you. Is there a way to mark your comment as answer? Or maybe you can add your comment in answer form so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: I've added it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149268/get-all-image-ids-from-the-media-library? After you get IDs array, you would simply need to convert it to delimited string. Let me know if you need help on that.